# R function with formula return has large memory imprint

Tags: r, memory, memory-leaks, r-formula

I have a function that fits a model which I call many times with the same big matrix (creating different formula inside each time). However, it seems that R saves copies of the data I use along the way, and so my memory explodes.

A simple deletion inside the function avoid this problem. **However, is there a general way to avoid retaining the whole environment each time?**

For example, running the following,

```
test <- function(X, y, rm.env=F){
  df <- cbind(y, X)
  names(df) <- c("label", paste0("X", as.character(1:ncol(X))))
  f <- formula(label~1, data=df, env=emptyenv())
  if (rm.env){
    rm(list=c("df", "X", "y"))
  }
  print(pryr::object_size(f))
  return(f)
}

X <- matrix(rnorm(700*10000), ncol=700)
y <- rnorm(10000)

m <- test(X, y)
print(pryr::object_size(m))

m <- test(X, y, rm.env=T)
print(pryr::object_size(m))
```

results in,

```
672 B
168 MB
672 B
1.13 kB
```

Note that the object in the first call has 168 MB behind it, so calling the first version over and over again eats a lot of memory fast.

Comment: `reformulate("1", "label", env = emptyenv())`

Comment: This also works, though I prefer the `enviroment(f) <- parent.frame()` trick in the next answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formula(label~1, data=df, env=emptyenv())` calls the S3 method `formula.formula`. Let’s have a look at its code:

```
stats:::formula.formula
# function (x, ...)
# x
```

… **the extra arguments are ignored!**

In other words, your assignment is the same as if you had written simply `f = label ~ 1`. In particular, its associated environment is the local environment, not the empty environment. To fix this, you need to manually reset it:

```
test <- function (X, y) {
  df <- cbind(y, X)
  names(df) <- c("label", paste0("X", seq_along(X)))
  # TODO: do something with `df` …
  f <- label ~ 1
  environment(f) <- emptyenv()
  f
}
```

Comment: Apparently, one needs to use `parent.frame()` as the environment to make of any use (otherwise, basic functions like `list` are not defined). But other than that, this solves the problem (note that I passed `f` into `lm`/`biglm` inside the function, and only the formula requires setting the environment explicitly).

Comment: For future reference, I ended up using `baseenv()` instead